# How can I define a custom style to an ARB text?

Tags: flutter, dart, intl

I have the following ARB file with the json:

```
"textToTranslate": "Text to translate with a {parameter} inside",
"@textToTranslate": {
    "description": "A parameter",
    "placeholders": {
        "parameter": {
            "type": "String"
        }
    }
},
```

I'm implementing it in Flutter as follows:

```dart
 Text(context.l10n.textToTranslate('text'), 
      style: const TextStyle(
      fontSize: 16,
      ),);
```

Is there a way I can put some custom style to the text passed as parameter to that l10n function?

I can set the style for the whole text but not the specific one in the parameter.

Thanks for any help!